# Lang's Complex Analysis 5.1.1 - prove holomorphy

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$  be analytic on an open set $U$.
Let $z_0\in U$ and $f'(z_0)\neq 0$.
Show that $\frac{2\pi i}{f'(z_0)}=\int_C\frac1{f(z)-f(z_0)}\,dz$ where $C$ is a small circle around $z_0$.

I think I'm pretty close to the answer.
My route involves considering $g(z)=\frac{z-z_0}{f(z)-f(z_0)}$ with $g(z_0)=\frac1{f'(z_0)}$.
$g$ is continuous on $U$, but I can't prove it's holomorphic - it's a straight shot through Cauchy's Integral Formula from there.
Hints only, please.

Edit: While I was waiting on answers, I found one of my own.
Essentially, we can say $f(z)=\sum a_n(z-z_0)^n\to g(z)=\frac1{\sum a_{n+1}(z-z_0)^n}$, which has nonzero constant term and so has an analytic inverse.
So, it's holomorphic!

Answer (score 0):

You know that $g$ is continuous on the whole of $U$, and is holomorphic on $U \setminus \{ z_0 \}$. You want to show that $g$ in fact is holomorphic on the whole of $U$.

Here is a possible approach.

- Define $h(z) = (z - z_0)^2 g(z)$. Show that $h$ is holomorphic on the whole of $U$, with $h'(z_0) = 0$.
- Write out Taylor series expansion for $h$, valid on some open ball in $U$ containing $z_0$.
- Deduce that $g$ has a Taylor series expansion on the same open ball.
- Deduce that $g$ is holomorphic on $U$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac1g$ is clearly holomorphic on $U\setminus\{z_0\}$, and has a power series at $z_0$ easily deduced from the one of $f.$